# Looking for Meteor Packages for Private Messaging

Tags: meteor, message

I'm trying to implement a standard chat function to send a private message between 2 user/client using MeteorJS. Is there any packages that is able to help with developing it ? This function should be commonly found in most web and if there is a live demo of it, it would be a huge help. Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is specifically a question-answer site, not a discussion forum. As it stands, your question is far too broad, and subject to personal opinion, both of which are considered 'off-topic' for StackOverflow. For further information, please review what is considered to be 'on-topic' for StackOverflow. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: That said, go check out the Socialize family of packages on Atmosphere: http://atmospherejs.com/socialize. `socialize:messaging` is likely what you want